# Python web-scraping script starts over during the loop

Tags: python

Below is the code, when I run the script, it starts over from the 1st page while running. The aim is to get the post title, date, and body from each page and then click next at the bottom of each page to start the process again.

Here are the includes:
import requests
import csv
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Xander/desktop/scraper/chromedriver')
URL = "https://www.jancox.com/jans-daily-news"
browser.get(URL)
URL_PAG = None
PAG = None


# Function Definition
def scrapeP(r):
    count = 0

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') # If this line causes an error, run 'pip install html5lib' or install html5lib 

    quotes = [] 
       
    table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'main-content'}) 

    for post in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'post'}):
        quote = {} 
        quote['title']          = post.h1.text

        print(quote['date_published'])

        doc = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')[0]
        time.sleep(2)

        doc.click()
        URL_PAG = browser.current_url
        count += 1
        PAG = True
        time.sleep(10)

        print(count, ' - ', URL_PAG)

        if(count % 10 == 0):
            filename = 'post.csv'
            with open(filename, 'a+', newline='') as f: 
                w = csv.DictWriter(f,['title', 'post', 'date_published']) 
                w.writeheader() 
                for quote in quotes: 
                    w.writerow(quote)
            quote.clear()
            

while True:
    if(PAG == True):
        browser.get(URL_PAG)
        r = requests.get(URL_PAG)
        print(URL_PAG)
        scrapeP(r)
    else:
        browser.get(URL)
        r = requests.get(URL) 
        scrapeP(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop never starts. The get request that you see is the one fired at line 3

PAG is None and you change its value inside your scrapeP function, so you never change its value outside scrapeP function's scope.

define

```
global pag
```

inside your scrapeP function to change its value from within a scrapeP

```
>>> PAG = None
>>> def scrapeP():
...     global PAG
...     PAG = True
... 
>>> scrapeP()
>>> PAG
True
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! However, when I declare using the global keyword.. whether inside or outside the function.. it returns an error saying PAG is not defined.

Comment: You have to declare page outside scrapeR (without globlal) AND inside scrapeR (with global)

Look at the minimum reproducible code sample i provided

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the function to click next and print in the for loop. I needed to allow the for loop to read the entire page before clicking next.

```
for post in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'post'}):
    quote = {} 
    quote['title']          = post.h1.text
    quote['date_published'] = post.time.text
    quote['post']           = post.div.text.strip()
    print(quote['date_published'])

    quotes.append(quote)

        
time.sleep(2)
doc = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a')[0]
    
doc.click()
time.sleep(2)
URL_PAG = browser.current_url
count += 1
PAG = True
time.sleep(2)

filename = 'post.csv'
with open(filename, 'a+', newline='') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['title', 'post', 'date_published']) 
    w.writeheader() 
    for quote in quotes: 
        w.writerow(quote)
quote.clear()
f.close()
```